# Inconsistent mainFields resolution using Webpack 4 in a monorepo

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4, lerna, yarn-workspaces

In a monorepo that is wired using Lerna and Yarn workspaces, one of the packages is a Next.js app, which depends on several packages internal to the monorepo.

All of the consumable packages in the monorepo are written in modern javascript, and have both a `main` field and a `module` field in their `package.json`s. [As per convention](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/pkg.module), the `main` field points to transpiled code, that uses CJS, while the `main` field points to code that is transplied except for for the conversion of ES modules to CJS.

As mentioned before, the package consuming the these packages is a Next.js app, which is build using Webpack 4. Strangely enough, one of the consumed packages is resolved to the `main` field, while all the rest are properly resolved to the `module` field.

I have even tried to manually set `resolve.mainField` to `[ 'module', 'main', ]`, which had no effect.

I couldn't find anything in the documentation that could explain this behavior, and any hint would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Facing the exact same problem in 2020.
Ever found a fix for the inconsistency?